# Use jScrollPane in a Chrome extension from within content script

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, jscrollpane

I'm writing a chrome extension - using content script.

Basically, I'm inserting a `div` inside another web page's `DOM` and inserting custom content in that. Need to make this `div` scrollable and am trying to make the scroll bars look better than the default.

After having inserted the `div`, running the following code to add `jScrollPane`.

```
$('#someFrame').contents().find('[class="my-scroll-pane"]').jScrollPane();
```

`someFrame` is the `ID` of an `iframe` already existent on the web page & `my-scroll-pane` is a CSS class I've applied to the `div` I inserted in the `iframe`.

In the `manifest.json` file, I've included the following:

```
"css": ["css/jscrollpane.css"],
"js": [ "plugins/jquery.min.js", "plugins/jquery.mousewheel.js", "plugins/jquery.jscrollpane.js", "js/my_script.js" ]
```

Didn't work. There was no javascript error thrown either.
I doubted if CSS not being a part of the main page's DOM was the problem. So, tried the following hack in the content script.

```
$('#someFrame').contents().find('head').append("<link id='my_css_jscrollpane' href='" + chrome.extension.getURL("css/jscrollpane.css") + "' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' />");
```

Didn't work. Again, no errors thrown. I confirmed that the link tag was correctly inserted inside the head section. Please guide about the right way to go about this.

Comment: In which script are you inserting this div and which script are you executing `jScrollPane()`? Is this the same content script? I don't think you can manipulate iframe content like that. You would need to inject content script to that iframe.

Comment: Both operations - inserting my div and calling jScrollPane - in the same content script - my_script.js. The div gets inserted, I can manipulate any content in the iframe from within this same content script.

Comment: Just for reference this is how I insert my div - $('#someFrame').contents().find('div[id="someExistingDiv"]').after('<div id="myNewDiv">My Content - that I need to make scrollable</div>');

Comment: Are you injecting all those content scripts into iframe (`all_frames` manifest flag)? Because you can't have javascript in parent page and expect it to affect iframe. I would just inject all those scripts into iframe and then do everything inside iframe, not from the parent page.

Comment: Just to clarify I meant if you are injecting `jquery.jscrollpane.js` into parent page instead of iframe then it wouldn't be accessible inside iframe.

Comment: I hadn't specified the all_frames manifest tag. So it must have defaulted to false. On setting it to true, didn't make a difference to the output. I'm not sure I followed you completely here. I'm using chrome's content-script - http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html - to inject html, manipulate existent DOM. And in terms of adding scripts/css to the page, I tried adding them inside the iframe - by doing this $('#someFrame') -- this selected the iframe & then I did - $('#someFrame').contents().find('head').append('mystyles.css')

Answer (score 0):

Responding to your last comment:

It didn't work because you are still do everything from a parent page. You need to inject all your content scripts into iframe and do everything inside iframe, not from parent page.

You can't access iframe js from parent page, so when you are calling `.jScrollPane()` on parent page it is still referencing to parent's page library, even though you are injecting it to both parent and iframe.

**UPDATE**

**manifest.json**:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://iframe.domain.com/*"],
      "css": ["css/jscrollpane.css"],
      "js": [ "plugins/jquery.min.js", "plugins/jquery.mousewheel.js", "plugins/jquery.jscrollpane.js", "js/my_script.js" ]
    }
  ],
```

**my_script.js**:

```
$(".my-scroll-pane").jScrollPane();
```

Comment: "You need to inject all your content scripts into iframe and do everything inside iframe" - how do I go about doing that? Could you help me with an example?